# Context Free Grammar Issue

Tags: context-free-grammar, language-theory

For starters this is a homework question. I have an idea but I am still not able to get the correct answer. I'm not asking for the answer I am just asking for help to answer the question.

I am currently trying to write a context free grammar for the language

```
a(iterated i times)db(iterated j times),  for i and j>=0,  and j = 2 * i.
```

So basically there are twice as many a's as b's and a d in between the 2. For example:

```
d,  adbb,  aadbbbb,  ……
```

Here is about what I have, I don't have much... I understand the concept of these CFG's I am just not sure about the logic for this question. I am not sure If i am even going the right direction...

```
S -> AdB
A -> EMPTY
A -> aAB
B -> DD
```

Thanks.

Comment: You mentioned you had an idea.  What was it?  If you give us an idea of your thought process we might be able to guide it more successfully.

Comment: You mean `i and j >= 0` right?  It'd be weird for them to be negative.

Comment: I have added my own work. To give an idea of my thought process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'll start off hints by saying that you only need 2 statements to solve this.  I'd rather see some of your work (even in the wrong direction!) if I'm to give you any more, though.

**EDIT**

Thanks for posting what you've got.  Here's a couple thought exercises that will hopefully get you moving in the right direction:

> Write a grammar that expresses a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> for n > 0 (ab, aabb, aaabbb, ...)

Wikipedia's article on CFG's has some help on this if you're still stuck.

> Write a grammar that expresses a<sup>n</sup>db<sup>n</sup> for n > 0 (adb, aadbb, aaadbbb, ...)

When you get that last one, you'll see the trivial addition to get to your grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a language you can list out like this, where each string in a substring of the following string, its fairly trivial to write a simple recursive grammar.  You need a rule to make the first (shortest) string, and a rule to make each longer string from the previous string.